# How do you make a dynamic range function in excel with a dynamic start and end cell?

Tags: excel, range

I have n export from a database of financial statement information. It only includes non zero rows. I am trying to use INDEX(MATCH) to copy the information and calculate key figures, KPI's etc. So far no problem.

The problem is the balance sheet contains multiple lines with the same text e.g. 'other receivables', so the basic INDEX(MATCH) will always take the first value. I can't solve it by counting the number of occurences either as if for example 'long term receivables' lacks 'other receivables' then that row is missing.

The solution I tried was using INDEX(MATCH) functions inside the INDEX(Match) 'array' section (first argument). It works fine if only the end point of the array is dynamic, but seizes to work when the starting value is dynamic as well. The idea is to isolate the 'other receivables' in e.g. short term receivables by searching an array starting from 'Short term receivables' and ending in 'Total short term receivables'.

To sum it up, the question is simple: How does one code an array with a dynamic start and end value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

https://exceljet.net/formula/get-address-of-lookup-result

You can get address of starting cell matching criteria (Short term receivables) and ending cell matching criteria (Total short term receivables) and you can thus create dynamic range.

Once get the starting cell dynamically you can select dynamic range using indirect (As the result of the following will be a string) and offset.

Referring ti the same link above
Following is the formula in H11
=CELL("address",INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Short Term Receivables",C:C,0),1))&":"&CELL("address",INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Total Short Term Receivables",C:C,0),1))

[image]

Comment: This does not work either. INDEX(array;row_num;col_num) is the formula, but it does not let you use the CELL(address) formula as an argument for both the start and finnish cell of the array.

Comment: can you share sample image of the the column with column number and row number with selection you want to make dynamically? Then, perhaps I will understand it better.

Comment: Or do you just want to start the dynamic range where the title "Short Term Receivables" first appear and ends at the cell where the "Total Short Term Receivables" appears in the column?

Comment: "Or do you just want to start the dynamic range where the title "Short Term Receivables" first appear and ends at the cell where the "Total Short Term Receivables" appears in the column?" -Yes

I just need the starting cell to be dynamic as "Short term receivables" does not appear on the same row for every company. For some reason, the array in INDEX seems to need a fixed starting cell to function. The end cell of the array being dynamic works just fine.

Comment: Please check edited answer. Thus you get the range in string format. You can use it with indirect function in other formulas. In this case you don't have to fix the starting cell also.

Comment: That is neat. Thx! Does this work by refering to that cell in the INDEX formulas 'array' section or by pasting the formula in there?

Comment: You can use it with any formula. Just make sure you are using Indirect function to convert the above string to address.                                                   
                  For Example, COUNTA(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Short Term Receivables",A:A,0),1))&":"&CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Total Short Term Receivables",A:A,0),1))))

Comment: If this answers your question, Please accept the answer and upvote. :)

Comment: This was a perfect solution and worked brilliantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a dynamic range using either INDEX or OFFSET.

The Index syntax uses the range operator, which is a colon - so INDEX(.. start cell ..):INDEX(.. end cell ..)

The Offset syntax uses an anchor cell and then a calculated row offset to the starting point and  number of rows argument to get to the end point - so OFFSET($Anchor$Cell,row offset to start cell,0,number of rows to end, number of columns)

Use MATCH to find the start and end rows

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to do. When I use INDEX and MATCH for both the starting and the ending position of the range, it seems not to work. When googling it I found out that the starting position needs to be fixed. What I'm looking for is a way to circumvent this.

Comment: Works for me when both parts are dynamic =INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(5,$A$2:$A$16,0),1):INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(10,$A$2:$A$16,0),1)